# "Anyone with the link" type of security

Tags: security

Have made this  pagehttp://simplemanscms.mortenkjarulff.dk

It is a php script.

It has some actions, for example, add ?action=build

If I kept those actions secret, would I then have the same type of security as, for example, when you share a YouTube video as "anyone with the link"?

Cheers

Comment: “build” is a word from a dictionary. Some could simply enumerate dictionary words. Contrary to that, YouTube video IDs are not meant to be a secret.

Comment: Yes but if I instead action=kii53ed7xvjfdt5xdtyuhdswr4775422fghjigffty7533ef and didn't post it here but kept it secret. Would I then have the same level of security? Can anyone read my php source where I also need to have the words?

Comment: ...it is like expecting to have a house 'sealed' and safe from thieves without any key/lock/whatever just because you put the knob in a corner of the main door with an unusual shape... that's the level of security that you will get.

Answer (score 0):

You would have the same type of security, as in: none. [read: security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). If you are fine with this then go right ahead.

As mentioned in the comments the "security" would be improved by using randomly generated hashes instead of dictionary words.

Maybe you should also look at [Basic HTTP authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: I fully understand that I should use a long word fx 100 random characters. The question is if I get the same level of security (or lack of) as when you share a YouTube video, Google document, dropbox file, etc as "anyone with the link" can access. I keep the secret word in my script

Comment: as I said, yes you would, you can only access the script with the random key... so that's the "security".